Counting characters in selected sections in document in Overleaf
I'm having some issues when using the answer provided here, as it seems the current version of Overleaf sets \jobname to output
Im still very much a novice in Latex, but using this example pulled from the linked answer, is it possible to make a minor change so it works in Overleaf?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreverb,savetrees}
% Compile with  --enable-write18 or --shell-escape options
\immediate\write18{texcount -tex -sum \jobname.tex > /tmp/wordcount.tex}
\begin{document}
\section[Count-me]{Count me}
This section is counted.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
%TC:ignore
\section{Ignore me}
A litle ignored text in the count.
%TC:endignore
\subsection{This is a subsection}
And some text with inline math ($E=mc^2$).
\subsection{And this is another subsection}
And some more text with display math \[E=mc^2\]
\subsection{One more subsection with a float}
This part of the text include  one figure float. 
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}\caption{A nice black box.}
\end{figure}
%TC:ignore  
\subsubsection*{Counts of words} 
\verbatiminput{/tmp/wordcount}
%TC:endignore  
\end{document}


just remove the /tmp/ from /tmp/wordcount.tex as you do not have write access to the filesystem outside of the document area

Thank you @DavidCarlisle, but it's still not working.
It just returns the same error where the word count should have been:
!!! File not found or not readable: output. tex !!!
(errors:1)
Do you have any other suggestions?


On overleaf they use --jobname=output so the generated pdf is always output.pdf but that changes \jobname and generated files but the source file is still whatever you called it (which is main.tex in my example here) so there is no output.tex and your write18 call to texcount fails looking for that file, change it to look for your real file name.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreverb,savetrees}
% Compile with  --enable-write18 or --shell-escape options
\immediate\write18{texcount -tex -sum main.tex > wordcount.tex}
\begin{document}
\section[Count-me]{Count me}
This section is counted.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
%TC:ignore
\section{Ignore me}
A litle ignored text in the count.
%TC:endignore
\subsection{This is a subsection}
And some text with inline math ($E=mc^2$).
\subsection{And this is another subsection}
And some more text with display math \[E=mc^2\]
\subsection{One more subsection with a float}
This part of the text include  one figure float. 
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}\caption{A nice black box.}
\end{figure}
%TC:ignore  
\subsubsection*{Counts of words} 
\verbatiminput{wordcount}
%TC:endignore  
\end{document}


Thank you @DavidCarlisle , that worked!
